# Why are my div elements not spaced out through my screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I am using bootstrap and trying to create a footer below my image. I want  one element to take 3 columns, one to take 6 columns and another to take 3, yet they all seem to be scrunched up to the left side, with hardly any margin. Why is this happening? And if I change one of my column amounts to anything higher than 12,  one or more goes to the next line, so I don't understand why they are all scrunched up to the left side.

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pipboy.app.css" />

</head>

...


<navbar class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    HP 90/90
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    LEVEL 1
                    <div class="level-progress"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    AP 50/50
                </div>
            </div>
</navbar>
```

**mystylingsheet**

```
.center-image img{

    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 300px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    filter:grayscale(1)sepia(100%)hue-rotate(55deg)saturate(7)brightness(1)contrast(2);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a width for outer container of navbar?  And `navbar`  should be `nav` right?

Comment: @kiranvj changing to nav doesn't do anything. I messed around with width through the browser and put it to a 100% and it didn't change anything

Comment: Can you try adding a container wrapper to all elements inside the body tag   `<div class="container">   your divs here  </div>`   You can also try the class `container-fluid`   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers

Comment: @kiranvj container instead of row?

Comment: Nope, container is a outer wrapper, I have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

What worked was removing class= 'row' and replacing it with class='container-fluid'. [image]

Comment: The problem is with the navbar, grid will not work well inside the navbar. If you dont need navbar, try removing that